# How to ensure ajax call is always made (not fetched from cache)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code.  The function is called multiple times depending on the user checking or unchecking checkboxes.

This works in all browsers except IE10/11.  In IE, the ajax call is only made once for a particular ID.  Subsequent calls are not actually sent to the server, but appear to be fetched from the cache.

In F12 developer tools, the call appears to be being made to the server, but Fiddler shows that it is not actually happening.

F12 also shows a 304 response to the call.

How do I ensure that the call is always made to the server?

```
function updateReportTypes(event) {
    var value = event.currentTarget.value;

    if (event.currentTarget.checked) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/PropertySearch/Order/AddReportType?id=" + value,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#reportTypes').html(data);
                hideProgress();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
                    $.ajax({
            url: "/PropertySearch/Order/RemoveReportType?id=" + value,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#reportTypes').html(data);
                hideProgress();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple set the:

```
cache: false
```

argument to `$.ajax()`.  When you do that, jQuery will automatically add a unique paramter onto the URL which prevents any caching of the request.

Using that option would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/PropertySearch/Order/AddReportType?id=" + value,
     dataType: 'html',
     cache: false,
     success: function (data) {
         $('#reportTypes').html(data);
         hideProgress();
     }
});
```

jQuery doc on this option: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Awesome.  That works, and the url looks like this:  PropertySearch/Order/RemoveReportType?id=9&_=1391478728832

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this specific issue, but if all else fails, you should be able to add a dynamic, cache-busting value, such as a timestamp, to make your URL unique:

```
 url: "/PropertySearch/Order/RemoveReportType?id=" + value + "&" + Date.now().toString()
```